# Redirect everything except one post

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use this htaccess for my Wordpress Site to redirect everything to Homepage. How can i exclude one single post from this? e.g. Mysite.com/thank-you

Thanks you!

```
# BEGIN redirect to homepage
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=301]
#END redirect to homepage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your set of conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thank-you/?$ [NC]
```

Much like the other conditions you already have, this one says that the rule can only take effect if the request URI does not start with `/thank-you` (trailing slash optional).

Comment: When possible, please explain your answer to make sure the OP can learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Add after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule ^thank-you$ - [L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

You just add another condition to your htaccess, so in case its the thank-you page it wont redirect

```
# BEGIN redirect to homepage
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thank-you$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=301]
#END redirect to homepage
```